# Pygame.display.update() disappearing

Tags: python, pygame

We have recently moved our school lab to Mac, and when I run some code to display an image from a file, the display appears then disappears immediately. I am using the 3.4 interpreter in Pycharm and Pygame version 1.9.2. Can someone please help?

Here is my code:

```
# displays a hard-coded filename in a window
import pygame
pygame.init()
picture = pygame.image.load("cards/S01.png")
pygame.display.set_mode(picture.get_size())
main_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
main_surface.blit(picture, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Is that all of the code?

Comment: You already asked the same question a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is the complete code, then that is the reason why its exiting immediately, because immediately after calling `pygame.display.update()` , the program exits. I do not think this should have been working before.

One thing you can do for this , add a loop to run till the user presses close, after your code -

```
running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
```

Comment: The bit of code was originally written on Raspberry Pi, where it works.

Comment: @larascit Did you try the above code?

Comment: Thank you for the loop tip. It works! The Pycharm IDE is still a bit mysterious, but my students will be able to develop their card games now. Thanks to FirebladeDan and Anand S Kumar.

Comment: @AnandSKumar: ...and you would gain 15 rep points  :D

Answer (score -1):

Put a

```
time.sleep(10)
```

after pygame.display.update() see if it stays up longer.